# A box in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a box in the middle of the window with css, but it doesn't work. The html element's height doesn't seems to be 100% for example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Box</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            body {
                margin: auto;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        box
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upload it to http://jsfiddle.net because I'm having a hard time understand what's going on.

Comment: The box should be in the middle of the frame: http://jsfiddle.net/aDRVp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not a good idea to mess with html and body making it display: table-cell or something

instead, try this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Box</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            div {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div>box</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will be aligned to the initial viewport, not the window.

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing the box inside a `div` element. Resizing the `body` won't work. You should use the following code:

```
<body>
    <div id="box">box</div>
</body>
```

And then your CSS should look like this:

```
#box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You can see a [**jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cZas/).